# Nginx with location and regex: url containing string to http server, appending whole path

Tags: regex, nginx

Lets stay I have a site at `https://www.example.com`
I want Nginx to redirect all requests to my site containing `/rss/` to a server I have at the address `127.0.0.1:4003`, appending `/api/v1` and the whole path that was passed in the original request.

For example, a request to `https://www.example.com/en/rss/blog` would go to `http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/en/rss/blog`.

I tried with `location`, matching the url with regex:

```
location ~ ^.*\b(\/rss\/)\b.*$ {
  rewrite ^.*\b(\/rss\/)\b.*$ /api/v1$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3007;
}
```

The redirection works, but is not appending the path, as I receive `Cannot GET /api/v1/rss/` as response.

This is a problem with the regex I suppose, it should capture the whole path instead of `/rss/` only; but how?

Any idea will be welcome!

Comment: Do not use word boundaries with special chars, try just `location ~ .*(/rss/.*)`

Comment: Ops, you are right, didn't notice it… thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word boundaries constructs are context dependant, in case of `\b\/rss\/\b`, the pattern will only match when the `/`s are preceded/followed with word chars, i.e. letters, digits or `_`.

In your case, the regex should look like

```
location ~ .*(/rss/.*)
location ~ (/rss/.*)
```

I.e.

- `.*` - match any text but line break chars
- `(/rss/.*)` - Group 1 (`$1`): `/rss` string and then any text but line break chars